# VB.NET: Prevent scrolling list view on removing item in windows form ListBox

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to prevent scrolling in a ListBox when removing an item from the list box and keep a limit of 5000 items. 
The following routine is called whenever a new entry is to be inserted to the list box.

```
lstLog.Items.Add(NewString)

If lstLog.Items.Count >= 5000 Then
    lstLog.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    lstLog.TopIndex = lstLog.TopIndex - 1
End If
```

However, when adding multiple entries in a loop, the scroll jumps up by multiple indices.
The following code works for scrolling but causes flickering:

```
Dim Temp As Integer

lstLog.Items.Add(NewString)

If lstLog.Items.Count >= 5000 Then
    Temp = lstLog.TopIndex
    lstLog.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    lstLog.TopIndex = Temp - 1
End If
```

I am also not sure why the second code works.
The routine is executed from a delegate using Invoke where we have a thread monitoring a Queue for entries which is dequeued and inserted into the list.

Comment: The value of `TopIndex` presumably changes when you call `RemoveAt` so getting that value after the call doesn't get you what you expect. Getting the value before the call ensures that the value you use to reset it is not affected by the method call.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it will work as desired but try calling `BeginUpdate` on the control first and then `EndUpdate` when you're done.

Comment: TopIndex should not change when removing an item. Tested this by adding a console writeline before and after the removeAt.
BeginUpdate and EndUpdate does reduce the flicker a bit to an acceptable level.